# Parse server custom change password not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I have written a function to change the password of a user in Parse Server.
which gives a success on changing in return but does not update the password in MongoDB.Not just the password ever profile data is not updated. Can anybody suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
function changePassword(req, res) {
    const _params      = req.params;
    const _user        = req.user;
    const _password    = _params.password;
    _user.setPassword(_password);
    _user.save();
    res.success("password updated");
}
```

Comment: Add an error handler to the save and see what the error is. Though I'd bet it's because you're trying to change a User's password using public write credentials instead of passing masterKey / the user's session token.

Comment: i tried with  `_user.save(null,{useMasterKey: true})`  as well but didn't work

Comment: The error message should be helpful.  Add a `.then()` after the save and call res.success / res.error as appropriate and catch the error message from the save.

Comment: @JakeT. this helped thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_user.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});`

Comment: I didn't work when i extracted  `{useMasterKey:true}` in a variable. but putting it as object worked don't know why that happened

Comment: Because useMasterKey is one of the keys you can set on an options object. There's also `error` and `success` which take closure blocks, and `session` or `sessionToken` which are strings and take a user's session token as credentials in lieu of master key. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped!

Comment: No problem. FYI when I said `session` or `sessionToken` it's because I forget which it is, not because you can use either. But that's how you make use of ACL permissions in Cloud Code to make sure a user has authorization to edit / find / destroy objects.